# Change loss in resolving git merge conflict

Tags: git, git-merge, git-diff, git-merge-conflict

I just encountered this issue for the third time in my life as a coder. This time I decided to find the root cause, so I spend some time to produce a minimum case.

https://github.com/myst729/git-diff-merge-loss

The steps:

1. Two features checkout their own branches (`a` and `b`) respectively, from the same base `master`.
2. The change of feature A has been merged: https://github.com/myst729/git-diff-merge-loss/pull/3/files?w=1

   1. Delete a block of code (line 34-57)
   2. Move a block of code (line 61-95) to the position where the previous block was (from line 34)

   [image]
3. Feature B has only one line changed. The point is, this line (line 70) is within the moved block in feature A https://github.com/myst729/git-diff-merge-loss/pull/4/files

   [image]
4. Feature B cannot be merged unless conflict resolved. However, line 70 in feature B has been moved to line 43 in `master` now. It's not even inside the conflict block. See line 43 in https://github.com/myst729/git-diff-merge-loss/pull/4/conflicts , or run `git merge master` locally on branch `b`

   [image]

This is a minimum case, but in real development, the feature may be more complicated, thus the change may be accidentally excluded when resolving conflicts. And ideally, two features that have dependent relationship should not be developed in parallel. But sometimes we have to form a special task force and rush for a deadline.

So the questions are:

1. Why does the diff shift happen?
2. How to avoid the code loss, as it's outside the conflict block and completely unnoticed?

Comment: You just have to use your brains when you resolve the conflict. However, you'd use them a lot better if you had a better view of what's happened! Configure your merge conflict style to `diff3` so that you are shown the original state of affairs.

Comment: @matt Use brains, agreed. I also doubt the two features to be developed in parallel. But as I stated, this happens when we are rushing for a deadline (I wasn't convinced either). Everyone is quite tired in the whole process, mistake happens. `diff3` is something new for me, I will try it.

Comment: You'll find that it makes a huge difference. But parallel code can be problematic even without a merge conflict; I've seen Git automerge get things wrong.

Comment: @Leo : by the way, it's a very nice thing that you managed to extract and share a section of repository which displays this issue. congratulations for that.

Comment: Yes, upvoted the question for exactly that reason: you prepared a great example.

Comment: @matt @LeGEC besides your suggestions, I find that there's an option **Git: Merge Editor** in VSCode. It reforms the conflict block that looks just like merging with `diff3`, even if I ran `git merge` with the default conflict style.

Comment: That was actually covered in LeGEC's answer: "external tools such as kdiff3 or meld". A merge conflict GUI simply consults the :1, :2, and :3 versions of the file, as I said in _my_ answer.

Comment: @matt You had me! This morning a colleague asked me for help. No conflicts at all, code loss. Guess what? Lots of indent changes that are easy to be ignored XD

Comment: @matt @LeGEC  [This PR#7](https://github.com/myst729/git-diff-merge-loss/pull/7) only add some lines. [This PR#8](https://github.com/myst729/git-diff-merge-loss/pull/8) reformed tree structure in the file, almost every line has changed but only a few if view diff with `-w` (reasonable as human being reviewer who wants to know the purpose). Since the review is based on LCA compare, nothing about PR#7 is noticeable in PR#8, and there is no conflict. After PR#8 merged, PR#7 changes gone (PR#9 is a merged demo in a backup branch).

Comment: Why there's no conflict (I guess it's because PR#7 doesn't remove a single line?), and how can we avoid such case in regards of github workflow? It happens silently even though we have enabled advanced tools and process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to supplement my earlier comments, I'm going to turn them into an answer. What I said was:

> You just have to use your brains when you resolve the conflict. However, you'd use them a lot better if you had a better view of what's happened! Configure your merge conflict style to `diff3` so that you are shown the original state of affairs.

To see what I mean, consider first what your merge-conflicted file shows. As you display in your screen shot, on the one hand we have HEAD, which is branch `b`:

```
        <el-form-item label="node:" prop="orgIdList">
          <org-tree-cascader
            :onlyAuthorized="true"
            :defaultProp="{
              expandTrigger: ExpandTrigger.HOVER,
              multiple: true,
              value: 'id',
              label: 'name',
              emitPath: false,
              checkStrictly: false,
            }"
            class="item-width"
            placeholder="selectnode"
            @updateOrgListValue="(handleUpdateOrgIdList as any)"
            ref="orgTreeCascaderRef"
          ></org-tree-cascader>
          <!-- <el-select
            v-model="state.form.orgList"
            :loading="state.orgLoading"
            multiple
            collapse-tags
            clearable
            placeholder="selectnode"
            size="mini"
            class="item-width"
            popper-class="exp-list-filter-select"
          >
            <el-option
              v-for="item in state.orgList"
              :key="item.value"
              :label="item.label"
              :value="item.value"
            ></el-option>
          </el-select> -->
        </el-form-item>
```

On the other hand, we have `master`, which is empty. This greatly reduces the likelihood that a human being is going to notice what has happened.

What *has* happened?

##### The LCA

In the LCA (the commit from which `b` "split off" from `master`), there is only *one* occurrence of the entry for

```
<el-form-item label="node:" prop="orgIdList">
```

It is at line 61, and its `checkStrictly` is `true`.

##### b

In `b`, into which we are merging, there is also only *one* occurrence of the entry for

```
<el-form-item label="node:" prop="orgIdList">
```

It is also at line 61, but it differs from the LCA in the value of `checkStrictly`, which is now `false`.

##### master

In `master`, which we are merging, there is still only *one* occurrence of

```
<el-form-item label="node:" prop="orgIdList">
```

but it is at line 34, and its `checkStrictly` is unchanged from the LCA.

##### So what happened?

What happened may thus be easily summarized: `b` changed one line of the group, but `master` moved the whole group.

##### How do I know?

Ah. It's because I know how to "ask questions" when we are paused during a merge conflict. In particular, I can say:

```
% git show :1:index.vue # the LCA version
% git show :2:index.vue # the `b` version
% git show :3:index.vue # the `master` version
```

##### How to discover what's happened?

So far, so good; but the practical problem, as you rightly say, is that the display of the merge-conflicted file itself, which I displayed at the start of this answer, is not very enlightening. In the merge-conflicted file, the line

```
<el-form-item label="node:" prop="orgIdList">
```

occurs *twice* — once at line 34, where `master` has it, and again in the display of HEAD, showing where `b` has it. But, as you rightly complain, the chances of a human being *noticing* this and working out what has happened, or even realizing that anything interesting *has* happened, seem very slim.

This is because, in part, your eye is drawn to the conflict area — and line 34, which is sort of the giveaway here, is not in that area.

##### Display more information!

But now let's say you have configured `merge.conflictStyle` as `diff3`. Then the LCA, which was not present in your version of the conflicted file, *is* present! Here is the entire display of the conflicted region in `diff3` style:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
            <el-form-item label="node:" prop="orgIdList">
              <org-tree-cascader
                :onlyAuthorized="true"
                :defaultProp="{
                  expandTrigger: ExpandTrigger.HOVER,
                  multiple: true,
                  value: 'id',
                  label: 'name',
                  emitPath: false,
                  checkStrictly: false,
                }"
                class="item-width"
                placeholder="selectnode"
                @updateOrgListValue="(handleUpdateOrgIdList as any)"
                ref="orgTreeCascaderRef"
              ></org-tree-cascader>
              <!-- <el-select
                v-model="state.form.orgList"
                :loading="state.orgLoading"
                multiple
                collapse-tags
                clearable
                placeholder="selectnode"
                size="mini"
                class="item-width"
                popper-class="exp-list-filter-select"
              >
                <el-option
                  v-for="item in state.orgList"
                  :key="item.value"
                  :label="item.label"
                  :value="item.value"
                ></el-option>
              </el-select> -->
            </el-form-item>
||||||| 1e59f94
            <el-form-item label="node:" prop="orgIdList">
              <org-tree-cascader
                :onlyAuthorized="true"
                :defaultProp="{
                  expandTrigger: ExpandTrigger.HOVER,
                  multiple: true,
                  value: 'id',
                  label: 'name',
                  emitPath: false,
                  checkStrictly: true,
                }"
                class="item-width"
                placeholder="selectnode"
                @updateOrgListValue="(handleUpdateOrgIdList as any)"
                ref="orgTreeCascaderRef"
              ></org-tree-cascader>
              <!-- <el-select
                v-model="state.form.orgList"
                :loading="state.orgLoading"
                multiple
                collapse-tags
                clearable
                placeholder="selectnode"
                size="mini"
                class="item-width"
                popper-class="exp-list-filter-select"
              >
                <el-option
                  v-for="item in state.orgList"
                  :key="item.value"
                  :label="item.label"
                  :value="item.value"
                ></el-option>
              </el-select> -->
            </el-form-item>
=======
>>>>>>> master
```

Between the display of `b` at the top and `master` (still empty) at the bottom, we now have the LCA. And thus we can now see clearly what happened between the LCA and `b`: the value of `checkStrictly` has changed.

We *still* do not necessarily realize what happened with `master`; it looks like it simply deleted this stretch, whereas in fact it moved it, and it now appears at line 34, which is not in the conflicted area. But we *do* understand why there's a conflict! One side changed this text, the other side "deleted" it. That was not at all obvious before, because we didn't know what the initial state of things was.

But we are now a bit more likely to discover this, because the line

```
<el-form-item label="node:" prop="orgIdList">
```

now appears *three* times: once in the `b` version, once in the `LCA` version, and once at line 34! That fact should be enough to get us thinking.

##### Braaaaaains

And that brings us back to my original comment. The best tool for working out what to do now is to use your brains. You have *two* things to decide: where should the `<el-form-item label="node:" prop="orgIdList">` entry go, and what should the value of its `checkStrictly` be? That is the problem that Git has set us; it's a true conflict, a decision that Git cannot perform automatically on its own.

The point is merely to gather enough information so that you know that that *is* the decision you have to make. What I'm suggesting is that with your display of the merge conflict, you are unlikely to work it out. With `diff3`, you are much more likely, and you could then use `git show`, as I demonstrated earlier, to put your finger on the history of what has happened and decide how to resolve it.

##### One more thing

Maybe I'm burying the lede here... Keep in mind that moving code is not a "thing" in Git's idea of a diff. If you move a line from one place to another distant place in the same file, that's two separate hunks: one where a new line appeared, and one where a line was deleted.

So in this case, nothing is going to get Git to see the code at line 34 as part of the merge conflict. It just isn't! It's a different area of the file from the conflict area — a place where some new lines appeared, that's all. And reading the conflicted file is never going to call this to your attention, as it is just not where the conflict is.

On the other hand, you, a human, can see quite well what happened if you say `git diff b...master`. That diff will show you how code appeared at line 34 and disappeared at line 61, and you, the human, will know what this means: the code was moved.

Answer (score 3):

You have to realize that, in general, tasks such as "computing the diff" or "detecting conflicts" all rely on heuristics: in a commit, you just store the contents before and after your modifications, but not the sequence of editions that lead from one to another.

---

In your precise example, it turns out part of the unexpected behavior comes from an indentation change :

- if you look at the code for `index.vue` in commit `1e59f94c7`, you see that there is an indentation between [lines 60 and 61](https://github.com/myst729/git-diff-merge-loss/blob/1e59f94c705b4c1b066466018f35e3323f2ceec1/index.vue#L60-L61)
- but you don't see it in the diff displayed [in the pull request](https://github.com/myst729/git-diff-merge-loss/pull/3/files?w=1#diff-f89ff9cc2719bab10e51475d37a3de21443cab59f9af15ec5ad80e1129d22fa3L60-L61), because line 61 of the original file is matched with an equivalent line with less indentation

This means that the displayed diff is obtained with `--ignore-space-change` or one of its variant.

In a terminal :

- you will see the same diff as in the merge request if your run :

  ```
  git diff --ignore-space-change 1e59f94 9c0adf9
  ```
- if you run `git diff` *without* the option, you will see a much different diff :

```
diff --git a/index.vue b/index.vue
index bf86463..a2241d7 100644
--- a/index.vue
+++ b/index.vue
@@ -31,68 +31,44 @@
               ></el-option>
             </el-select>
           </el-form-item>
-          <el-form-item label="related Feature:" prop="featureIdList">
-            <el-select
-              v-model="state.form.featureIdList"
-              filterable
-              remote
+          <el-form-item label="node:" prop="orgIdList">
+            <org-tree-cascader
+              :onlyAuthorized="true"
+              :defaultProp="{
+                expandTrigger: ExpandTrigger.HOVER,
+                multiple: true,
+                value: 'id',
+                label: 'name',
+                emitPath: false,
+                checkStrictly: true,
+              }"
+              class="item-width"
+              placeholder="selectnode"
+              @updateOrgListValue="(handleUpdateOrgIdList as any)"
+              ref="orgTreeCascaderRef"
+            ></org-tree-cascader>
+            <!-- <el-select
+              v-model="state.form.orgList"
+              :loading="state.orgLoading"
               multiple
               collapse-tags
               clearable
-              reserve-keyword
+              placeholder="selectnode"
               size="mini"
-              placeholder="keyword"
               class="item-width"
               popper-class="exp-list-filter-select"
-              :remote-method="featureRemoteMethod"
-              :loading="state.featureLoading"
             >
               <el-option
-                v-for="item in state.featureIdList"
+                v-for="item in state.orgList"
                 :key="item.value"
                 :label="item.label"
                 :value="item.value"
               ></el-option>
-            </el-select>
+            </el-select> -->
           </el-form-item>
         </div>
         <transition name="filter">
           <div v-show="state.isShowAll" class="filter-form-advanced">
-            <el-form-item label="node:" prop="orgIdList">
-              <org-tree-cascader
-                :onlyAuthorized="true"
-                :defaultProp="{
-                  expandTrigger: ExpandTrigger.HOVER,
-                  multiple: true,
-                  value: 'id',
-                  label: 'name',
-                  emitPath: false,
-                  checkStrictly: true,
-                }"
-                class="item-width"
-                placeholder="selectnode"
-                @updateOrgListValue="(handleUpdateOrgIdList as any)"
-                ref="orgTreeCascaderRef"
-              ></org-tree-cascader>
-              <!-- <el-select
-                v-model="state.form.orgList"
-                :loading="state.orgLoading"
-                multiple
-                collapse-tags
-                clearable
-                placeholder="selectnode"
-                size="mini"
-                class="item-width"
-                popper-class="exp-list-filter-select"
-              >
-                <el-option
-                  v-for="item in state.orgList"
-                  :key="item.value"
-                  :label="item.label"
-                  :value="item.value"
-                ></el-option>
-              </el-select> -->
-            </el-form-item>
             <el-form-item label="owner:" prop="admin">
               <el-select
                 v-model="state.form.admin"
```

This influences how conflicts are detected : if the merge is performed with the second diff (that's what happens without some form of "ignore-space-changes), the line `checkStrictly: true -> checkStrictly: false` falls within a modified block.

From a terminal, you can test that :

```
# from branch master:
git merge -X ignore-space-change b
```

does not trigger conflicts, and produces the code you expect in this specific case -- with some oddities in the indentation.

---

As @matt suggested : external tools such as `kdiff3` or `meld` do a better job at figuring this out in your example, but the only general advice regarding merging is : do audit them (with your brains on).

Comment: I don't know if there is an option to instruct `github` to try to merge with `-X ignore-space-change`

Comment: On GitHub, adding URL query `w=1` turns **ignore space** on. You can remove the query, but that doesn't affect the online conflict resolve editor. I tried `diff3` as Matt suggested, it does work.